# Inserting an integer value in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to show an integer value in a TextBox in my C# Windows Forms application (GUI).
I have an int32 value available. I could not find a container like a TextBox that takes int values. The TextBox only accepts Strings. How do I type cast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in .NET can be transformed to a string in one way or another by using the "ToString()" method.

**Example**

```
int x = 5;
string y = x.ToString();
```

Comment: Can I ask why we have you use "()" at the end? @womp

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 10;
TextBox1.Text = i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

TextBox.Text = MyInteger.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ToString() method to convert the integer to a string.

int x = 10;

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways:

```
        int i = 123893232;
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());//123893232
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i));//123893232
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:C}", i));//123 893 232,00 zł(Polish)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:D}", i));//123893232
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:E}", i));//1,238932E+008
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:F}", i));//123893232,00
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:G}", i));//123893232
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:N}", i));//123 893 232,00
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:P}", i));//12 389 323 200,00
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:X}", i));//76275F0
```