# display integer value in textbox in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have one Text Box in windows application. This Text box can only hold a `String` value and not an `integer`. How can i pass the `integer` as a `String` to the text box?

```
int a=3;

//textBox1->Text = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with VisualC++, you can convert integer to string as follows:

```
    yourIntegerValue.toString();
```

in your case:

```
    textBox1->Text = a.toString();
```

Please consider using the search function, next time you are tempted to ask. This question is a duplicate for:

[Inserting an integer value in a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280328/inserting-an-integer-value-in-a-textbox)