# CS0029 Compile Error - implicit conversion when outputting a integer to a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an inventory system for a project. I've been given some base code for classes, hence the lists and objects.

When I try to return all these values from the file into a `RichTextBox` using WinForms, I get a compile error (specifically for implicit conversions).

I'm just wondering if there is an additional script for displaying integers in WinForms other than the usual `textbox.txt = "some numbers"`.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Bike> Bikes = new List<Bike>();
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
        int invCounter = 0;
        int invLength = lines.Length / 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < invLength; i++) //for each bike
        {
            string make = lines[i + invCounter++]; //store the make
            string type = lines[i + invCounter++]; //store the type
            string model = lines[i + invCounter++]; //store the model
            int year = int.Parse(lines[i + invCounter++]); //store the year
            string wheelSize = lines[i + invCounter++]; //store the wheel size
            string frameType = lines[i + invCounter++]; //store the frame type

            //store the security code
            int securityCode = int.Parse(lines[i + invCounter++]); 

            //create a new bike object with the details stored above
            Bike bk = new Bike(make, type, model, year, wheelSize, frameType,
                securityCode); 

            Bikes.Add(bk); //add the bike to Bikes list
            foreach (Bike bike in Bikes)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.Type;
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.SecurityCode; // Error here
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.Make;
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.Model;
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.Year; // Error here
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.WheelSize;
                richTextBox1.Text = bk.Forks;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `Text` property is a `string` type while some of the `Bike` properties you are trying to store in `Text` are not `string` types. You need to look into converting and casting data types. Microsoft has an article about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

Comment: Your `foreach` loop as a whole doesn't seem right... Do you really want to loop through your entire `Bikes` list every time you add a new `Bike` to that list?

Comment: Can you post the definition for the `Bike` class?

Comment: @LewsTherin so would the sample compile if I used a 'long' data type? Or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting an integer value in a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280328/inserting-an-integer-value-in-a-textbox)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Im not sure where the issue with the `foreach` loop it was the working code I was given, it worked perfectly fine for command line but compiles an error when I move to WInForms?

Comment: @Jaxix You can only store `string` data in a variable or property that has a `string` datatype. `Text` is a `string` type, so anything you try to store in it must first be converted to a `string`. I'll give you another hint, google [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @Jaxix - It may appear to work, but if you trace through it (perhaps on paper if that helps), it looks like it's doing a lot of unnecessary looping. Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's correct. It might be correct, but it sure doesn't look right.

Comment: @LewsTherin Yeah the `ToString()` is the solution ive found but where in the code would it go? The class where its defined? Or before the `foreach` loop?

Comment: @Jaxix If you are struggling with this, you probably need to find a good C# tutorial. Data type conversions are basic C# concepts. I would highly recommend against trying to cobble together an inventory system without a solid foundation in the basics of C# first. Look at @lionthefox's answer to see where `ToString()` goes.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I concede that its probably not the most advantageous way to do it, but im still very new to the language and I just took the code ive been given and worked with it but ill definitely look into it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign an `int` to a `string` property (`Text`). There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `string`, so you have to do it explicitly. Just call `.ToString()` on the `int` you want to assign.

```
foreach (Bike bike in Bikes)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.Type;
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.SecurityCode.ToString();
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.Make;
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.Model;
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.Year.ToString();
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.WheelSize;
    richTextBox1.Text = bk.Forks;
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the fact that `richTextBox1.Text` will contain only the value of `bk.Forks`.

Comment: That's correct. I just solved his compiling error, without addressing any logical flaws at all, since his code doesn't make too much sense in general.

Comment: @LewsTherin beat me to the punch, would I be right to fix this using `AppendText`?

Comment: @Jaxix It really depends on what you want to display. Appending the text will just join the strings in the single richTextBox1, without any spaces or line breaks between them.

Comment: @lionthefox My initial aim is to display them in a structure similar to CSV with rows and columns?

Comment: To achieve this you should do some research an set up a ListBox. Here's something to start with:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/listbox-in-C-Sharp/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732054/how-can-i-add-an-item-to-a-listbox-in-c-sharp-and-winforms

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can try:

```
richTextBox1.Text = bk.SecurityCode.ToString();
richTextBox1.Text = bk.Year.ToString();
```

to convert a number to a `string`.

Comment: This is a C# question.