# Update and display constantly changing variable value in threads using winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm new to `winforms` so when I click onto a button, it will perform a while loop where `i++` is done inside the loop. So i will need the value to be printed out to keep track of the current value of `i`. How do I link the value to the `text/label` in winform? 
Here's the function that I'm incrementing the `i/j/k`:

```
public static void TestSequence1()
        {
            int i = 0;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Console.WriteLine("Sequence1 working on thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            while (true)
            {
                waitHandle.WaitOne();
                int a = ++i;
                label1.Invoke((Action)(() => label1.Text = a.ToString()));
                //Console.WriteLine("Current i value: {0}", i);
            }
        }
```

I will need to show the value of `j` (shown above) cause I would like to know if the value of `j` stop increamenting when I click `pause` button to pause the thread as the `workHandle.WaitOne()` is inside the loop. Just trying whether I placed it right and also the `waitHandle.Set()` where I placed it in the `Start` button.

Comment: Do you mean something like `int k = j; label1.Invoke((Action)(() => label1.Text = k.ToString();`?

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280328/inserting-an-integer-value-in-a-textbox) does not solve my problem. The value is **constantly incrementing** and I need something like `UI.refresh`. I have no idea why people downvoting as they like. This feature is stupid.

Comment: Why do you need to refresh? Can't you just invoke when you update the value?

Comment: @Enigmativity Saw in the link above that I can try `int i = 10;
TextBox1.Text = i.ToString();` but does it change accordingly to my `i++`?

Comment: No, but after to you increment `i` you then invoke. `int k = ++i; label1.Invoke((Action)(() => label1.Text = k.ToString();`. Does that work for you?

Comment: @Enigmativity Do i put it in the while loop? Also, I'm getting this error: `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Form1.label'`

Comment: Yes, where you increment the value you then need to update the label. I don't know what controls you have created so I guessed you had `label1`, but you need to ensure you use a control that you have created.

Comment: Added 
`int a = ++i;
var mc = new Form1();
mc.label1.Invoke((Action)(() => mc.label1.Text = a.ToString()));` into my while loop but then I've received **System.InvalidOperationException**

Comment: Why are you creating a new form? Isn't `TestSequence2` in an existing form? If not you need pass a reference to the form/control you're trying to update.

Comment: No idea what exactly i need to do. Cause if i dont do `var mc = new Form1();` I will be receiving this error: `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Form1.label'`

Comment: Where does `TestSequence2` live? Inside an existing form?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, inside an existing form which is Form1

Comment: Then you just do what I've been suggesting `label1.Invoke((Action)(() => label1.Text = k.ToString()));` - `label1` is an existing control on `Form1` and there is no need to do `Form1.label1` (as that doesn't work).

Comment: But exactly where should I put those lines of code at. I've edited the code above and that's where I put the code at. But putting at there raise an error which is `An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Form1.label'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231399/discussion-between-thanish-k-and-enigmativity).